# Fetch data in background thread using Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, async-await, nsfetchrequest

I'm facing an issue with accessing the result from a perform block in Core Data when fetching countries from the database in a background context. Here's the code snippet:

```
actor Repository {
    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    private func fetchAllCountries() async -> [MCCountry]? {
        let request = getFetchRequest()
        let backgroundContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
        do {
            let result = try await backgroundContext.perform {
                let countries = try backgroundContext.fetch(request) as? [MCCountry]
                let attributeValue = countries?.first?.countryCode
                debugPrint("Country code \(String(describing: attributeValue))") // returns value
                return countries
            }
            debugPrint("Country \(String(describing: result))") // crashes here
            return result
        } catch {
            debugPrint("error \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
Task {
             await repository.fetchCountries { result in
                if let result {
                    for value in result {
                        debugPrint("Value is \(String(describing: value.countryCode))") //returns nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that even though I can access the result inside the perform block, the returned result from backgroundContext.perform seems to be inaccessible. When I try to access the result after the block, I encounter an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I expected to receive the result from the perform method and return it immediately in the fetchAllCountries method.

Am I missing something in my understanding? Shouldn't I expect a result from the perform block? Can someone please help me identify what's wrong with the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated but how many countries do you have stored, do you really need to use asynchronous code for this fetch?

Comment: I have a database with approximately 100 countries using a background thread. This approach was chosen to address performance concerns flagged by the performance monitoring tool (Sentry), which detected that the fetch operation was being performed on the main thread. Additionally, whenever the app is opened, the countries are synchronized, so each country is being fetched from the database in a loop before updating the corresponding record from the api response.

Comment: The question about how many was rhetorical, I know roughly how many countries there are on the world . Still doubtful if you need asynchronous code for such a small number of I assume small objects for this but this discussion is off topic so let’s leave it.

Comment: 1 you are using async await incorrectly. 2 first chunk of code does not match second chunk. Watch “Meet async await”

Comment: you could have just sped it up on main thread by adding `countryCode` to the `propertiesToFetch` array which would have included it in the initial fetch of object IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundContext you are fetching on is being deallocated after your function executes. And then all the objects fetched on it will not be valid anymore.

If the purpose of the fetch is to display data, then it must occur on the viewContext.

If you have a large query to preprocess your data, you could return ObjectIDs instead of objects in your async fetch and then create a predicate to fetch objects contained in objectIDs with those on the viewContext to actually get the objects to display.